# How to import the electron ipcRenderer in a react / webpack 2 setup

Tags: reactjs, webpack, electron

using a electron, react (es6 / jsx), sass, pouchdb and webpack 2 setup. I fail to import or require ipcRenderer to make communication between main and renderer process possible. My setup can be found here: https://github.com/wende60/timeTracker

Any hints how to get the ipcRenderer into a react component?

Cheers, jo

Answer (score 17):

```
const electron = window.require('electron');
const ipcRenderer  = electron.ipcRenderer;
```

I think it is the better solution because it avoid ejecting the React app.

Comment: Note with electron V12 there's an issue [due to contextIsolation](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9920#issuecomment-797143298)

Comment: @ecoe Please refer to my answer which resolves the context isolation problem

Answer (score 10):

I suggest you read my response [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9920#issuecomment-575839738).

You'll want to set up your app like this:

**main.js**

```js
const {
  app,
  BrowserWindow,
  ipcMain
} = require("electron");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let win;

async function createWindow() {

  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false, // is default value after Electron v5
      contextIsolation: true, // protect against prototype pollution
      enableRemoteModule: false, // turn off remote
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js") // use a preload script
    }
  });

  // Load app
  win.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, "dist/index.html"));

  // rest of code..
}

app.on("ready", createWindow);

ipcMain.on("toMain", (event, args) => {
  fs.readFile("path/to/file", (error, data) => {
    // Do something with file contents

    // Send result back to renderer process
    win.webContents.send("fromMain", responseObj);
  });
});
```

**preload.js**

> ** Update: DO NOT use `send` key value as property name. It will overwrite on `win.webContents.send` method and comes to do nothing when you try to call `win.webContents.send('your_channel_name')` inside your main process `main.js`. Better to use better names like `request` and `response`.

```js
const {
    contextBridge,
    ipcRenderer
} = require("electron");

// Expose protected methods that allow the renderer process to use
// the ipcRenderer without exposing the entire object
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    "api", {
        //send: (channel, data) => {
        request: (channel, data) => {
            // whitelist channels
            let validChannels = ["toMain"];
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, data);
            }
        },
        //receive: (channel, func) => {
        response: (channel, func) => {
            let validChannels = ["fromMain"];
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender` 
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => func(...args));
            }
        }
    }
);
```

**index.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        window.api.response("fromMain", (data) => {
            console.log(`Received ${data} from main process`);
        });
        window.api.request("toMain", "some data");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Sajad - I've written code using the above methods, what have you encountered a problem using `send` as the property on the window from the preload.js?

Comment: I tried to send an event from my main process on some keyboard shortcut to my ipcRendere using `win.webContents.send('channel', someArgs)` and failed to receive data on in `ipcRendere.on('channel', func())`. it took 1 hour to find out that the problem is when you try to append the `api.send` and `api.receive` method to window object using `contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld` it will affect the `win.webContents.send` method and you will lose the `data` arg contents, cause your calling function you passed not the `webContents.send` method.

Comment: It's all I know for now and I'll try to find what is the right behavior of 'contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld'. But I did change the`send` to `request` and I'm all good now...

Comment: I am currently using this method on electron 12 and unejected CRA (create-react-app) seems to be the clean working solution...

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. This solved that issue for me:

Add in the `webpack.config.js`:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ExternalsPlugin('commonjs', [
            'electron'
        ])
    ]
    ...
}
```

Then you can use it with

```
import {ipcRenderer} from "electron";
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint Mattias. I found an alternative solution using webpack-target-electron-renderer like here: https://github.com/wende60/timeTracker So I can develop react, scss and the pouchdb-access running 'web' with hot-reloading and import electron only when i run 'electron' cheers, jo

Comment: this works great,would love to know how you knew to do this

Comment: `The externals configuration option provides a way of excluding dependencies from the output bundles. Instead, the created bundle relies on that dependency to be present in the consumer's (any end-user application) environment.`

So does that mean this solution only works presuming electron is installed by the user?

Answer (score 6):

As of May 2020, I think [Erik Martín Jordán has said it best](https://erikmartinjordan.com/electron-react-ipcrenderer):

Create a preload.js file:

```js
window.ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
```

On main.js:

```js
// Create the browser window.
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    alwaysOnTop: true,
    frame: false,
    fullscreenable: false,
    transparent: true,
    titleBarStyle: 'customButtonsOnHover',
    show: false,
    width: 300, 
    height: 350,
    webPreferences: {
        // UPDATE: for electron > V12 consider setting contextIsolation and see: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9920#issuecomment-797491175
        nodeIntegration: true,
        preload: __dirname + '/preload.js'
    }
});

// Blur window when close o loses focus
mainWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => mainWindow.webContents.send('ping', '') );
```

mainWindow variable on this file will preload the preload.js file. Now the React component can call the window.ipcRenderer method.

In the React app.js:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
    
    useEffect( () => {
        
        window.ipcRenderer.on('ping', (event, message) => { 
            console.log(message) 
        });
                
    }, []);
            
    return (
    <div className = 'App'></div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: seems can't assign to `window.` in preload any more, i had to use this `contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("ipcRenderer", ipcRenderer)`

Comment: and 'ipcRenderer' method `on` is only available in preload script

Comment: @DanD. for what it's worth I switched to using [Tauri](https://tauri.app/) years ago. Such an amazing tooling if you can afford to migrate I never looked back.

Comment: Interesting. Electron has posed a lot of challenges. I might check out https://tauri.app/ as an alternative to Electron.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking into this topic just recently and I found a solution for doing some some ipc between electrons main.js and the React part of the application. Since both, `import {ipcRenderer} from 'electron';` after adding the plugin to the webpack modules and `const ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer;` produced some errors I ended up requiring electron in the resulting page and adding it to the window.

In the `index.html` I did something like this

```
<body>
  ...
  <script>
    window.ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
  </script>
  <div id="root">
  </div>
  ...
</body>
```

In reacts `index.js` I did something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
// ...
if(window.ipc)
ipc.on("some-event", (event, someParameter) => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <SomeElement value={someParameter} />,
    document.getElementById("root")
  );
})
// ...
```

In order to make this work i started the react page from the electron app, in the `main.js` I did something like that.

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require("electron"};
const exec = require("child_process").exec;

let main;
app.on("ready", () => {
  exec("node start", (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    console.log("" + stdout);
    console.log("" + stderr);
  });

  main = new BrowserWindow();
  main.loadURL("http://localhost:3006");
  main.on("close", () => {main = null});
});
```

because electron is running on the same port I added a `.env` file to my project that contained

```
PORT=3006
```

I used the `create-react-app my-prj` (`npm install -g create-react-app`) command for my base project it looked something like this

```
my-prj
 |-package.json
 |-main.js
 |-.env
 |-node_modules/
 |-public/
    |-index.html
 |-src/
    |-index.js
```

Hope this post was of any help.

Answer (score -1):

Found a good solution for this issue using [webpack-target-electron-renderer](https://github.com/chentsulin/webpack-target-electron-renderer) So I can develop the web-part in a localhost environment with hot-reloading. electron is required only in the electron environment.

You can see a working example here:
https://github.com/wende60/webpack-web-and-electron-example, forked from acao's webpack-web-and-electron-example and updated for webpack 2 and hot-replacement.

If you are interested in a webpack, electron, react, sass and pouchdb setup have a look here:
https://github.com/wende60/timeTracker
Work is still in progress...

Answer (score -4):

```
import { ipcRenderer } from "electron"
import { Component } from "react"
```

...

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
   render(){
      ipcRenderer.send("event", "some data")
      return (<div>Some JSX</div>)
   }
}
```

Comment: hi Sators, this is something that i - of course - tried out before, but i end up in something like: **bundle.js:49593 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "fs"**
    at webpackMissingModule (bundle.js:49593)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:49593)
    at Object.splitPathRe (bundle.js:49604)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:658)
    at fn (bundle.js:86)
... **npm install fs** was not the solution here...