# require is not defined in a Electron-React-Webpack-Typescript app with ipcRenderer.on

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, electron

In an Electron-React-Webpack-Typescript app, when inserting into /src/renderer.ts these lines:

```
ipcRenderer.on('messageFromMain', (event, message) => {
  console.log(`This is the message from the second window sent via main: ${message}`);
});
```

I get this error:

[image]

This is the entire /src/renderer.ts file:

```
import './app';

console.log('renderer.js is so happy to say you  hello....');

import { ipcRenderer, BrowserWindow } from 'electron';

ipcRenderer.on('messageFromMain', (event, message) => {
  console.log(`This is the message from the second window sent via main: ${message}`);
});
```

Based on what I found here: // [How to import the electron ipcRenderer in a react / webpack 2 setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44008674/how-to-import-the-electron-ipcrenderer-in-a-react-webpack-2-setup) , I've also put in tools/webpack/webpack.plugins.js :

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = [
  new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin(),
 new webpack.ExternalsPlugin('commonjs', [
    'electron'
  ])
];
```

I tried to import electron in renderer.ts as a window component:

```
const electron = window.require('electron');
```

But got:

```
window.require is not a function
```

It must be something related to the interaction among electron, react and webpack, but I didn' find any solution yet.

With

```
webPreferences: {
  nodeIntegration: true, // Changed 
  enableRemoteModule: false,
  contextIsolation: false, // Changed
  nodeIntegrationInWorker: false,
  nodeIntegrationInSubFrames: false,
  preload: MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY,
},
```

it doesn't give `require is not defined`

when inserting in renderer.ts:

```
ipcRenderer.on('messageFromMain', (event, message) => {
  console.log(`This is the message from the second window sent via main: ${message}`);
});
```

I tried to import ipcRenderer in preload.js as follows:

```
window.ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
```

But I get

```
TS2339: Property 'ipcRenderer' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.
window.ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
   |        ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Following these indications: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9920#issuecomment-672449613
I also handled ipcRenderer in preload.js as follows :

```
import { ipcRenderer, IpcRenderer } from 'electron'

declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface Global {
      ipcRenderer: IpcRenderer
    }
  }
}

// Since we disabled nodeIntegration we can reintroduce
// needed node functionality here
process.once('loaded', () => {
  global.ipcRenderer = ipcRenderer
})
```

But I get the same error in renderer.ts:

```
ERROR in src/renderer.ts:14:24
TS2304: Cannot find name 'ipcRenderer'.
```

So.. the hurdle can be expressed as:
how to keep for security purposes

```
nodeIntegration:false,
contextIsolation: true,
```

and being able in the same time to import ipcRenderer in renderer.ts?
There must be a way to make renderer.ts and main.ts communicate with each other, while keeping the environment as much as secure as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Now it seems working with:

in main.js

```
webPreferences: {
  nodeIntegration: false,
  enableRemoteModule: false,
  contextIsolation: true,
  nodeIntegrationInWorker: false,
  nodeIntegrationInSubFrames: false,
  preload: MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY,
},
```

preload.js :

```
import { ipcRenderer, contextBridge } from 'electron';

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
  'electron',
  {
    doThing: () => ipcRenderer.send('do-a-thing')
  }
)
```

index.d.ts :

```
declare interface Window {
  electron: {
    doThing(): void
  }
}
```

and renderer.ts :

```
import './app';

console.log('renderer.js is so happy to say you  hello....');

window.electron.doThing();
```